# ReactiveExtensions Observable FromAsync calling twice Function

Tags: c#, task, system.reactive

Ok, Trying to understand Rx, kinda of lost here.

FromAsyncPattern is now deprecated so I took the example from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2012/03/12/reactive-extensions-v2-0-beta-available-now.aspx) (section Light up Task with Rx), and it works, I just made a few changes, not using await just wait the observable and subscribing.....

What I don't understand is Why is called Twice the function SumSquareRoots?

```
 var res = Observable.FromAsync(ct => SumSquareRoots(x, ct))
                                      .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

            res.Subscribe(y => Console.WriteLine(y));

            res.Wait();


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Samples();
    }

    static void Samples()
    {
        var x = 100000000;

        try
        {
            var res = Observable.FromAsync(ct => SumSquareRoots(x, ct))
                                      .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

            res.Subscribe(y => Console.WriteLine(y));

            res.Wait();
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Timed out :-(");
        }
    }

    static Task<double> SumSquareRoots(long count, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var res = 0.0;
            Console.WriteLine("Why I'm called twice");
            for (long i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                res += Math.Sqrt(i);

                if (i % 10000 == 0 && ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Noticed cancellation!");
                    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }
            }

            return res;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Which overload are you calling there? I can't find it on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321543(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: it seems is not there, but the signature is this one. 
public static IObservable<TResult> FromAsync<TResult>(Func<CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> functionAsync);

i'm using Rx2.0.21114 // Assembly System.Reactive.Linq.dll, v2.0.20823.0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason that this is calling SumSquareRoots twice is because you're Subscribing twice:

```
// Subscribes to res
res.Subscribe(y => Console.WriteLine(y));

// Also Subscribes to res, since it *must* produce a result, even
// if that result is then discarded (i.e. Wait doesn't return IObservable)
res.Wait();
```

`Subscribe` is the `foreach` of Rx - just like if you `foreach` an `IEnumerable` twice, you could end up doing 2x the work, multiple `Subscribe`s means multiple the work. To undo this, you could use a blocking call that doesn't discard the result:

```
Console.WriteLine(res.First());
```

Or, you could use `Publish` to "freeze" the result and play it back to > 1 subscriber (kind of like how you'd use `ToArray` in LINQ):

```
res = res.Publish();
res.Connect();

// Both subscriptions get the same result, SumSquareRoots is only called once
res.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
res.Wait();
```

The general rule you can follow is, that any Rx method that *doesn't* return `IObservable<T>` or `Task<T>` will result in a Subscription(*)

* *- Not technically correct. But your brain will feel better if you think of it this way.*

Comment: Paul, is it correct to assume that any Rx method that results in a Subscitpion will return an IDisposable??